# PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field using @OneToOne or @ManyToOne

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to solve problem with Error accessing field. So here are two dependencies that can be the reason. The first one:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Proxy(lazy=false)
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "games")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "authorId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.settype")
    private Set<Game> games = new HashSet<Game>();
```

And here is the class Game:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "game")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Proxy(lazy = false)
public class Game {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = com.exam.entity.User.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "UserID", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer authorId;
```

But all the time I've got the same log:

> SEVERE [http-nio-8081-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.Integer com.exam.entity.User.id] by reflection for persistent property [com.exam.entity.User#id] : 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.Integer com.exam.entity.User.id] by reflection for persistent property [com.exam.entity.User#id] : 1] with root cause
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Integer field com.exam.entity.User.id to java.lang.Integer

Comment: Have your user class has public setter/getter method for id feild?

Comment: Yes, sure. I've added lombok library and annotated class as @Data.

Comment: Did Lombok annotation processor produce any warnings during compilation?

Comment: no, nothing at all. I just want to setd request in json like:

Comment: { "title":"Some game",
 "author":1
}

Comment: Any solutions??